# Microsoft Word 2007 removing spaces between words

Tags: dropbox, microsoft-word-2007

I'm working with another person and sharing Microsoft Word documents with them via dropbox and I'm using Word for Mac 2011 and they are using Word 2007 on windows.  When they open one of the shared documents, about every hundred words or so, a space between two or more words in omitted in their version.  If they then save the document and send it back, it is missing on my end now.

Why do these spaces get omitted when opening on the other machine and how might we prevent this corruption from occurring?

Comment: What happens if they never open it and you manually download and open the version which you uploaded to DropBox? Or better yet, upload yours to dropbox, have the person retrieve it from dropbox, and email it to you, what would happen?

Comment: If I open the version in dropbox, there is no issue.  I don't want the document emailed since it is confidential, so cannot perform that experiment.  However, when they opened it in another application (Open Office) it had the spaces.