# Word 2013 removes spaces between words

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, microsoft-word-2013

Having already checked this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/748990/microsoft-word-2007-removing-spaces-between-words), where there are no solutions, I proceed to my question.

It happens with some .docx files, created by other users (using Word 2007) and sent to me by email. I do some editing of text and formatting and send it back to the users (including the ones who had originally sent me the files). The file received by them have no spaces between words.

This becomes a huge deal breaker.

What have I tried:

1. Tried renaming
2. Inspect document and remove everything (except
   Headers and Footers)
3. Tried saving in 97-2003 format
4. Step 3 above and
   then reconvert it to Word 2013 format
5. As we use custom fonts, I even
   tried embedding the fonts

Obviously, none of my methods work. Looking for solutions.

PS: When they send me back the my file with no spaces, I also experience the problem. Further, all other users are using Word 2007 or Word Viewers.

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because they are using Office 2007. It is a known issue which is resolved by installing Office 2007 SP3.

> When you open a Microsoft Word 2010 document in Microsoft Word 2007,
>   spaces are missing between some words in the document.  To resolve
>   this problem, install the 2007 Microsoft Office Suite Service Pack 3
>   (SP3).

[source](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2633585)

The reason you see the problem when they send the file back is because they have saved the file in that format.